# FileNotFoundException when using one-click install

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reference, publish

### What Happens?

---

I have been having an issue on this now for the past week and I feel like i get closer and closer each day but can't put my finger on what it is.

I have purchased a license of a Third-Party program called 'Streamcoders' (*lets you encoder a live stream*). When installing this program it gives you (*as far as i know*) an x86 and x64 version of two .dll's '*MediaBase*' and '*MediaSuite*'. I have added the x86 version into my references as this is the one I need.

The properties of these dll's are :

- `Embed Interop Types = false.`
- `Copy Local = true.`
- `Aliases = global.`
- `Specific Version = false.`

So i go to publish my application. I specify the location, and then specify that i want the user to install the application from a Web Site. This all works and the application is installed.

I go to the clients machine and install the application and I get an error:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MediaSuite.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.`

### My Tests + Code

---

So when looking through my code I tried to add `MessageBox.Show("");` to pin-point where the error occurs.

So on my Login page constructor, i call a method `CheckUserRegistry()`:

```
        try
        {
            if (Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER", "URL", "").ToString() == string.Empty)
            {
                //User has not used the application before.
                MessageBox.Show("NO URL FOUND");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("GENERATE");
                //User has used the application before and is generating that user a session GUID.
                Global.podiaClient = new podiaPublish.PublishClient();
                Global.podiaClient.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(string.Format(Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER", "URL", "").ToString() + "/wcf/publish.svc"));
                //Global.podiaSession = Global.podiaClient.Login(Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER", "UID", "").ToString(), Global.Decrypt(Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER", "PWD", "").ToString()));
                Global.podiaSession = Global.podiaClient.Login(Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER", "UID", "").ToString(), Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER", "PWD", "").ToString());


                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            //Global.HandleError(ex);
            MessageBox.Show("here");
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString());
            return false;
        }
```

It successfully hits the `MessageBox.Show("GENERATE");` and then after that seems to hit the `catch` and displays the error.

If i comment out the lines below the code does not error. `podiaPublish` is a Service Reference in my project.

```
Global.podiaClient = new podiaPublish.PublishClient();
Global.podiaClient.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(string.Format(Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER", "URL", "").ToString() + "/wcf/publish.svc"));
Global.podiaSession = Global.podiaClient.Login(Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER", "UID", "").ToString(), Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER", "PWD", "").ToString());
```

Does anyone have any clue as to what is going on?